# Why is unique_ptr operator-> not const-overloaded?

Tags: c++, constants, smart-pointers

`std::unique_ptr::operator->` has the signature

```
pointer operator->() const noexcept;
```

So `operator->` is const but returns a mutable pointer. This allows for code like:

```
void myConstMemberFunction() const
{
    myUniquePtrMember->nonConstFunction();
}
```

Why does the standard allow this, and what is the best way to prevent usage as presented above?

Comment: I  expected it's because the operator `.` cannot be overloaded.

Comment: In C++ `const` is shallow. An `int* const` also allows you to modify the pointed to object.

Comment: The same code would be allowed if the pointer were not smart. The constness applies to the pointer, not to the pointee.

Comment: We have [`std::experimental::propagate_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) if you want to propagate it.

Comment: Common misconception about `const`.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for the tip on `propagate_const`. It seems like a good way to ensure const correctness with smart pointer members.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Think about it like a normal pointer:

```
int * const i;
```

is a `const` pointer to a non-`const` `int`. You can change the `int`, but not the pointer.

```
int const * i;
```

is a non-`const` pointer to a `const` `int`. You can change the pointer but not the `int`.

---

Now, for `unique_ptr`, it's a question of whether the `const` goes inside or outside the `<>`. So:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> const u;
```

is like the first one. You can change the `int`, but not the pointer.

What you want is:

```
std::unique_ptr<int const> u;
```

You can change the pointer, but not the `int`. Or perhaps even:

```
std::unique_ptr<int const> const u;
```

Here you can't change the pointer *or* the `int`.

---

Notice how I always place the `const` on the right? This is a little uncommon, but is necessary when dealing with pointers. The `const` always applies to the thing immediately to its left, be that the `*` (pointer is `const`), or the `int`. See http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/17/continental-const-placement/ .

Writing `const int`, might lead you to thinking `int const *` is a `const`-pointer to a non-`const` `int`, which is wrong.

Answer (score 7):

This replicates the semantics of traditional pointers. A `const` pointer is a pointer that cannot be mutated. However, the object it points to can.

```
struct bar {
  void do_bar() {}
};

struct foo {
  void do_foo() const { b->do_bar(); } // OK
  bar* const b;
};
```

To avoid mutating the pointee, you need the `unique_ptr` equivalent of const pointer to const, or

```
const std::unique_ptr<const bar> b;
```