# Which methods should be const?

Tags: c++, methods, constants

The `const` keyword should be used on class methods to indicate that the calling object is not modified by this method. But what is the exact semantics of the latter? I can think of three options: A class method should be const if and only if

1. (weakest) it does not modify the bits and bytes of the object's store
2. (stronger) it does not modify the object (as in 1) and also not the referenced objects which are owned by the object
3. (strongest) it does not modify the object and also not any object referenced by it (whether it is owned or not)

What is the "right" way? Is there a common consense among the programming community?

For example, the standard library's containers const semantics satisfy at least 2 obviously. On the other hand, strangely, the *-operator of std::unique_ptr does not even satisfy 2: it is const but returns a non-const reference to the pointed to object, although the object is owned be the std::unique_ptr object by definition.

Another example:

```
class X
{
private:
    int& intref;

public:
    X(int& intref): intref(intref) {};

    void modifyRef(int& another) const
    {
        this->intref = another;
    }
};
```

Following 2, the const on the method is ok, since intref references something which is not owned by the object. Following 3, the const should be deleted.

Comment: "The const keyword should be used on class methods to indicate that the calling object is not modified by this method." -- ***wrong***.  It indicates that the ***called*** object is not modified by this method.

Comment: I'll go one more level down, 0(logical const-ness) Where you are opaquely modify object state.

Comment: @gjha That's not one level down, but a step sideways.

Comment: `this->intref = another` does not reassign the reference, but assigns to the referenced variable, `another` should be passed by value.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334043/why-is-unique-ptr-operator-not-const-overloaded/34334173

Comment: The compiler only checks your '1.' (ignoring mutable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those three.

Remember that C++ `const` means *logical* constant, not *physical* constant.

Naturally you may only modify `mutable` members in case the object is declared constant, but aside from that you only have to preserve the logical state.

So, does your method change the logical state of the object?

Comment: I embarrassingly must admit that I can't remember that C++ const means logical constant, because I didn't know that before. But I see the point. I think I have used it that way intuitively before, and then was confused when I was trying to set up rules for using const on methods (which lead to the 3 points above). I will read further about logical constness, any recommendations appreciated.

Comment: Is it true that const on class methods is mainly for the public ones, or should they also be used for private methods?

Comment: If you aren't const-correct throughout, it won't work. So, do it for the private methods too.

Comment: Oh yes, right. Thanks for the hints to enhance my view on C++!

Answer (score 1):

Level 0 (Logical const-ness) Where you are allowed to opaquely modify the object state.

Consider an example of a `Cache` class, which has a find() method, and which finds an element in local map, failing to find in local map it goes ahead and searches in DB.. etc. and finally updates it's local map with retrieved value.

Here `find()` method in `Cache` class can be const and it will give a cleaner interface for class. A user of class will not be bothered by the internal mechanism of element retrieval.

The example you have provided does not satisfy `logical const-ness`

Answer (score 0):

This is a good reference as an answer to my question complementing the other answers:
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness